# Search Array to find corresponding value

Tags: php, arrays

All,
I'm trying to write a sql statement to be something like this:

```
$sql = "Select id, rating from ratings";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$resultset = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

So the resultset would have the database results (there will be like 50+ results sometimes). What I'm trying to do is basically search through the array for a value and if it finds that value in the id column it would echo out the rating that is associated with that line.

What is a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: just use where... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($resultset as $result){
  if($result['id'] == $searchId){
    echo $result['rating']."\r\n";
  }
}
```

Where your $searchId is the id you're searching for.

Comment: If you found your result, it were nice to end the loop with a break ;)

Comment: your condition is always true

Comment: @Hannes, no, it depends on the value of $searchId

Comment: @Isiscode You are right, but you can do a break when you find the wanted item to avoid going through all the items of the array as matzino suggested :P

Comment: @Isiscode Thanks, when I do a print_r of my $resultset, it only has one value. Shouldn't that value contain all of the rows returned by mysql or does it stop at one?

Comment: @Nobita, yes but you're both assuming that 'id' is unique, it may not be. It might be the case that looping through the rest of the array is the desired behaviour - one cannot assume, I was simply answering the question asked and nothing more! :P

Comment: @user1048676, correct, it should contain all of the rows returned.

Comment: you changed your code from `=` to `==` after i wrote my comment ...so yes now it is not always true

Comment: @Isiscode agreed. I assumed the ID was the primary and unique key :)

Comment: @Isiscode Hmm, when I do a print_r of the $resultset I get the following: Array ( [0] => 361487424 [song_id] => 361487424 [1] => 5 stars [rating] => 5 stars) Even though I have at least 13 rows returned when I run that same query in mySQL

Comment: @user1048676: `mysql_fetch_array` only returns the first row of the result set as an associative array (just like you found).  `mysql_query` returns the actual result set.  You must loop over the result set: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Answer (score 2):

Use a WHERE clause in your sql statement to only return the row(s) you want.

```
$sql = "Select id, rating from ratings Where id = '<the id you want>'";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just care about a particular **ID-Rating** row, there is no need on fetching all of them, change your SQL to look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, rating FROM ratings WHERE id = '$myID'";
```

Where `$myID` is the ID value of the particular row you want to fetch.

**EDIT**: If you want to fetch more than one ID, you can use a query like:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, rating FROM ratings WHERE id IN (value1,value2,...)
```

Comment: I only wanted to call the database once because I want to search for a value like 50 times. I figured I'd try and get all the data in an array from the database in one call instead of checking the database each time. I think it would be quicker that way.

Comment: @user1048676 If you want to look for A value (a particular value with a given ID) like 50 times, you still want to use a WHERE clause in your query.

Comment: Thanks, I know that though. I basically have another foreach loop that has values that I need to see exist in my database. I didn't want to have to make 50 different calls to the database to search for a new ID. I figured I'd just get all the data and then loop through the array instead. It's probably faster then hitting the database that many times.

Comment: Yes but if you know the IDs you can still fetch just those with the IN clause in the WHERE to fetch multiple values. Let me update the answer for you.